# Sed removes matches from output

Tags: regex, bash, sed, ps

I'm trying to extract the process numbers starting with the number 3.

When using `ps | sed "/^\s\+3/"`, I get an error message : `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: missing command`

I then added a global flag : `ps | sed "/^\s+3/g"` which succeeds but instead of showing me all matches, it removes all the matches found.

This is the unchanged output :

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3128 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
 5279 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
 5280 pts/8    00:00:00 sed
```

In the end, this is the output I get : 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD

```
 5219 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
 5220 pts/8    00:00:00 sed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-n` parameter to print the lines which matches a particular pattern. And note that, basic sed won't support  the pattern `\s` (which is used for matching whitespaces).

```
ps | sed -n '/^ *3/p'
```

OR

```
ps | sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*3/p'
```

Comment: From man pages, -n is : suppress automatic printing of pattern space. Isn't suppressing the contrary of what we want here? (Btw this works, but I have a hard time understanding it)

Comment: sed reads the input line by line. so it appends line to pattern space before doing any operation on that particular line. S if `/^ *3/` matches the line which is present in the ps, then -n and p causes automatic printing of those lines.

Comment: Another way is `ps | sed '/^ *3/!d'` i tried adding to the answer in an edit(as it is too similar to be an answer on it's own and also the question is closed) but it got rejected :(

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like sed isn't really the best tool for the job. Try awk:

```
ps | awk '$1 ~ /^3/'
```

This prints all lines whose first column begins with 3.

Comment: Thank you but using sed is really what I am looking for here :) +1 anyway